# play anorm, create a model from json without passing anorm PK value in the json

Tags: json, playframework, anorm

```
object Users  {

  implicit object UserReads extends Reads[User] {
    def reads(json: JsValue) = JsSuccess(User(
      Id((json \ "id").as[String].toLong),
      (json \ "name").as[String],
      (json \ "email").as[String]
  }
  implicit object UserWrites extends Writes[User] {
    def writes(user: User) = JsObject(Seq(
      "id" -> JsNumber(user.id.get),
      "name" -> JsString(user.name),
      "email" -> Json.toJson(user.email)
  }

  def view(id: Long) = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(Json.toJson(User.find(id)))
  }

  def all() = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(Json.toJson(User.findAll()))
  }

  def save = Action(parse.json) { request =>
    val userJson = request.body
    val user = userJson.as[User]
    try {
      User.create(user)
      Ok("Saved")
    } catch {
      case e: IllegalArgumentException => BadRequest("Error")
    }
  }
}


case class User(
  id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned,
  name: String = "",
  email: String = "")
```

The above two are my controller & model, when I send the User data [id, name, email] as json using angular JS, it creates the User object in the database. But it should be able to create when I input only [name, email] or just [name] as email could be null. If I'm not wrong I should adjust these in the reads and writes method of User, is it?.

Also, can we have two reads/writes for different pursposes, if so how can that be achieved - throw some light. Thanks.

One Issue fixed with the following:

```
case class User(
  id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned,
  name: String = "",
  email: Option[String])

implicit object UserReads extends Reads[User] {
    def reads(json: JsValue) = JsSuccess(User(
      Id((json \ "id").as[String].toLong),
      (json \ "name").as[String],
      (json \ "email").asOpt[String])
  }
  implicit object UserWrites extends Writes[User] {
    def writes(user: User) = JsObject(Seq(
      "id" -> JsNumber(user.id.get),
      "name" -> JsString(user.name),
      "email" -> Json.toJson(user.email))
  }
```

Now email can be null, but what about id - PK[Long]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not compile this, but it should work:

```
case class User(
  id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned,
  name: String = "",
  email: Option[String])

implicit object UserReads extends Reads[User] {
    def reads(json: JsValue) = JsSuccess(User(
      (json \ "id").asOpt[Long].map(id => Id[Long](id)).getOrElse(NotAssigned)
      (json \ "name").as[String],
      (json \ "email").asOpt[String])
  }
  implicit object UserWrites extends Writes[User] {
    def writes(user: User) = JsObject(Seq(
      "id" -> JsNumber(user.id.get),
      "name" -> JsString(user.name),
      "email" -> Json.toJson(user.email))
  }
```

Basically you take the id as `Option[Long`] like you did with the email. Then you check if it is set and if yes you create the Pk instance with `Id[Long](id`) and if not you provide the `NotAssigned` Pk singleton instance.

**Additional Tip**

Alternatively you can try to use

```
implicit val jsonFormatter = Json.format[User]
```

It will create the `Reads` and the `Writes` for you directly at compile time.
There are two problem with this if you are using an anorm object directly:

First you need a Format for the Pk[Long]

```
implicit object PkLongFormat extends Format[Pk[Long]] {
  def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Pk[Long]] = {
    json.asOpt[Long].map {
      id => JsSuccess(Id[Long](id))
    }.getOrElse(JsSuccess(NotAssigned))
  }
  def writes(id: Pk[Long]): JsNumber = JsNumber(id.get)
}
```

Second it does not work, if you do not send an id at all, not even with value null, so your client needs to send `{"id": null, "name": "Tim"}` because it does not even try to call the PkFormatter which could handle the JsUndefined, but simply gives you an "validate.error.missing-path" error

If you don't want to send null ids you cannot use the macro `Json.format[User]`

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Can we have two reads/writes for different pursposes, if so how can that be achieved - throw some light. Thanks.

Comment: As argument in the second parameter list: `Json.toJson(myUser)(UserWrites)`, `Json.toJson(myUser)(UserWritesFull)` or if you stored it in the user: `Json.toJson(myUser)(User.FullWrites)`

Answer (score 0):

Type `anorm.Pk` is almost exactly like `scala.Option` in form and function. Avoid writing concrete `Reads` and `Writes` for all types it *might possibly* contain. An example that follows the `OptionReads` and `OptionWrites` implementations is as follows:

```
implicit def PkWrites[T](implicit w: Writes[T]): Writes[Pk[T]] = new Writes[Pk[T]] {
  def writes(o: Pk[T]) = o match {
    case Id(value) => w.writes(value)
    case NotAssigned => JsNull
  }
}

implicit def PkReads[T](implicit r: Reads[T]): Reads[Pk[T]] = new Reads[Pk[T]] {
  def reads(js: JsValue): JsResult[Pk[T]] =
    r.reads(js).fold(e => JsSuccess(NotAssigned), v => JsSuccess(Id(v)))
}
```

This way, you support every `T` for which there's a respective `Reads[T]` or `Writes[T]`, and it's more reliable in handling `Id` and `NotAssigned`.